# Is there a way to auto-bind a Spring GraphQL @Argument input to QueryDSL Predicate?

Tags: spring, graphql, querydsl

In REST you can bind HTTP query params to the QueryDSL Predicate like this:

```
@QuerydslPredicate(root = MyClass.class) final Predicate predicate
```

What is the equivalent for GraphQL?

Say I have a custom input type

```
input MyFilter {
  status: String
  this: Float
  that: String
  #  ..
}
```

and would like to seamlessly bind it to a GraphQL @Argument and subsequently pass it the QueryDSL predicate and then on to the @GraphQlRepository.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @theprogrammer not yet :/